# Restrict imported CSS to given component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, create-react-app, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

I am currently building out the admin side of my first React app, which was started with **create-react-app** (also styled-components if it matters in this case).

Instead of building out my own custom admin I'm using [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction). Part of this involves importing the [styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-css):

`import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';`

I'm doing this in my admin container component. The problem I'm running in to is that once I import those styles the global selectors are applied site-wide, even though I only want them in the admin side of things.

Is there a standard practice for restricting imported styles to a given area of your app? I'm pretty unfamiliar with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a style loader supporting CSS modules spec.

This loader would namespace your component's css classes with a parent unique class. This would prevent your css classes from leaking to global namespace.

Example, I had used isomorphic style loader from kriasoft which did this.